# Can I disable chrome's auto translate function for visitors to a given page on my site?

Tags: google-chrome, translation

I know how to disable this feature for pages that I visit, but what I'm looking for is a way to tell other user's Chrome browsers not to offer translation a particular page on my site.

Is there some kind of meta tag I can use?  Alternatively, can I indicate that a particular element on the page should not be translated?

Reason: The controls which slide down from the top of the page cause my page to resize, which changes the content, which makes the control slide up, which resizes the page, which changes the content, which causes the controls to slide back in.  Rinse and repeat.  The page dances.

The page itself is a map, and the content it wants to translate are all proper names and shouldn't be translated anyway.  If alternate names exist in other languages, I provide them myself.  Generally I'm against taking away features from the browser that users might like, but in this case it really makes sense.  So please don't answer saying that I shouldn't be doing this.  I've weighed up the options.

Comment: What's the link it sounds fun/annoying for the user

Comment: Yes, you can! See the link as below.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228972/disable-chrome-translation-bar-on-my-website

Comment: Related (from Pro Webmasters SE): [How can I prevent Google mistakenly offering to translate a page?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/how-can-i-prevent-google-mistakenly-offering-to-translate-a-page)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out by [Bertrand Marron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228972/disable-chrome-translation-bar-on-my-website/7229002#7229002), you can do this via:

```
<meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

Thanks to @jacksun101 for linking the post here with SO.

Comment: Here's documentation about using the notranslate meta tag on Google's support site: http://support.google.com/translate/?hl=en

Comment: Note, I rolled back an edit to the code in this answer, because it's a direct quote from Google's support site, and it works as is. If someone can site why it should be changed, then we can reinstate the edit.

Comment: The meta element has no such attribute as "value", and never has - the attribute should be "content" (and meta elements with a "name" should have a "content").  However, this is a common enough mistake that it appears most browsers tolerate it without issue.  Google, in this case, is wrong to recommend "value" - basically it looks like that advice is in error, and it only happens to work because browsers tolerate that mistake.  People who use "value" are probably confusing it for the "<input>" element.

Comment: This seems to be invalid and should be `content` instead of `value`! https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/special-tags?hl=en&visit_id=637512798290365052-2401742211&rd=1

Answer (score 1):

> Google does not use language meta-data since we've found that it's
>   generally incorrect. Using HTTP headers, HTML meta tags or
>   element-level lang-attributes does not have an impact on Google's
>   language recognition, so unless you want to do that for other purposes
>   (eg screen-readers), you can probably skip on that.
>
> One thing to keep in mind is that Google has no problem recognizing
>   multiple languages per page. So even if we should recognize that a
>   part of the page is say in Italian (perhaps when you write about
>   Italian hotels), and we show a "translate this page" link in the
>   search results, we'll probably still be able to recognize that it's
>   mostly in English. A simple way to check that is to use the advanced
>   search options to select a specific language and do a site:-query for
>   your site.

Source: [John Mueller - Webmaster Trends Analyst at Google Switzerland](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/how-can-i-prevent-google-mistakenly-offering-to-translate-a-page)

> That's correct - at the moment there's no way to make the "Translate
>   this page" link disappear from the webmaster's side. I'll pass your
>   feedback on to the team though, maybe that's something they can
>   consider for the future. – John Mueller Nov 5 '10 at 18:08

Comment: That quote applies to trying to hide the "Translate this page" link on Google search results, not trying to hide the translation toolbar that comes with Google Chrome.